# Remove accidentally committed massive file on github

Tags: git, github

I accidentally committed a massive file several commits ago, Ive since deleted it and committed that, but when I try to push I get **error :**

```
'remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.'
```

Is there any way I can just push the current state of the repo and ignore those files I deleted?

UPDATE

When I run git rebase  I get this..

```
        C:\Data\unity\GameX4 [patching]> git rebase 4a877be9acb7dbabb46b9aec367d68b2fec7c884
    First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
    Applying: smaller particles again
    Applying: sdgs
    Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
    M       Assets/01_GRAPHICS/03_UNITY_MATERIALS/metaballmat.mat
    Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
    warning: Cannot merge binary files: Assets/01_GRAPHICS/03_UNITY_MATERIALS/metaballmat.mat (HEAD vs. sdgs)
    Auto-merging Assets/01_GRAPHICS/03_UNITY_MATERIALS/metaballmat.mat
    CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Assets/01_GRAPHICS/03_UNITY_MATERIALS/metaballmat.mat
    Failed to merge in the changes.
    Patch failed at 0002 sdgs
    The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
       c:/Data/unity/GameX4/.git/rebase-apply/patch

    When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
    If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
    To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".

    C:\Data\unity\GameX4 [(1697860...)|REBASE +0 ~3 -0 !1 | +0 ~0 -0 !1]>
```

Comment: Are you the only one using the repository? How many commits has it been since you've committed this large file?

Comment: no, and it was 8 commits ago. I have very spotty and slow internet here (about 40kbps up) And github has refused to work in the past so when syncing I mistook the problem of this massive file as being normal connection issue, so I continued working, thinking that I will push later when internet is good enough for it to work again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not pushed this big file (and I presume that's the case due to the error), just do a `git rebase -i <some commit before the one where the large one was added>` and then delete the commit where you added the large file. The commits will get rewritten and you'll have a string of commits that don't have the offending one. You'll be able to push this.

When you do a rebase -i, you'll see something like this pop up in your editor. When I say "delete" a commit, you simply have to delete the line that that refers to it in the list (e.g. suppose `faed141` is the commit where you added your large file, simply delete the line that refers to it in the list below). Then save and exit your editor. Git will rewrite the tree dropping that commit and you're good to go.

```
pick 53542eb Changes a
pick a30f028 Adds b
pick faed141 Adds c
pick 5446c0f Adds d

# Rebase fbd339b..5446c0f onto fbd339b
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

Comment: How can you 'delete' a commit? Also will I lose other stuff I made in that commit that I want to keep, and what about the 8 commits of stuff Ive made since then? thanks!

Comment: Reread the answer. Use "rebase -i", and squash the commit that added the big file, and the commit that removed it.

Comment: Can you be more specific? How does one 'squash' a commit?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It's not squashing. It's deleting. The operations are different.

Comment: @GuyeIncognito I've updated my answer with an example

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim: since OP mentions *Also will I lose other stuff I **made in that** commit*, I think that an example with `e`, `git diff HEAD~ -- MASSIVE_FILE | git apply --reverse; git commit --amend` would help him more...

Comment: True. I missed that. I think though that making this change at that commit (rather than at HEAD) will keep the history cleaner.

Comment: Thanks @eckes – this example deserves a more prominent place! It's exactly what I needed, when I accidently included a file change in a commit a while ago. It means: do a `rebase -i`, choose `e` to edit the commit and then run `git diff HEAD~ -- THE_FILE_TO_EXCLUDE  | git apply --reverse; git commit --amend`. Great. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In your case, use [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) to remove the offending files from all the previous commits

1. Use the command to remove `file_name_to_remove`

   ```
   git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
     'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch file_name_to_remove' \
     --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
   ```
2. After the filter branch is complete, verify that no unintended file was lost.
3. Now add a .gitignore rule

   ```
   echo "file_name_to_remove" >> .gitignore
   git add .gitignore && commit -m "removing filename"
   ```
4. Now do a push

   ```
   git push -f origin branch
   ```

You will need to do a forced push in case you have already pushed your branch becuase the commits were re-written. Otherwise, if the changes are local only, you can do a normal push as well. The added advantage is that if you have added this file in multiple commits, you can completely remove it from the history from across all commits.